# GWT grid cells don't wrap

Tags: javascript, java, css, gwt

I'm using a GWT GridPanel.  I want one of the columns to wrap but nothing I've tried works.  In the associated css file, I've tried:

```
.x-grid3-cell-inner .x-grid3-col-note {
    overflow: visible; white-space: normal !important;
}
```

where note is the name of the column that I want to wrap.  Didn't work.
I've tried:

```
.x-grid3-cell {
    white-space:wrap;
}
```

Didn't work.  I've tried:

```
.x-grid3-cell-inner {
    cell-wrap: true;
}
```

Didn't work.  Anyone have a *simple* solution that works?

EDIT: I also tried setting the id in the ColumnConfig like this:

```
ColumnConfig[] columns = new ColumnConfig[] {
        new ColumnConfig("Note", "note", 130, true, null, "note"),
        new ColumnConfig("Date", "date", 65, true)
};

ColumnConfig c = columns[0];
c.setId("noteColumn");
```

Then in the css I added:

```
#noteColumn {
    overflow: visible; white-space: normal !important;
}
```

But that didn't work either.

Comment: This doesn't look like GWT's built in grid's styling - can you provide some more context?

Comment: When you create a GWT project, it creates a css template file ProjectName.css.  When I look at the rendered html, I see the above class names for the target table cells.  So I added css to that file to try and get them to wrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [GWT-Ext widget](http://gwt-ext.com/docs/2.0.4/com/gwtext/client/widgets/grid/GridPanel.html). In the documentation there are some examples on how to wrap cell contents.

> For example, use this to wrap all cell contents globally

```
 .x-grid3-cell-inner {
      overflow: visible; white-space: normal !important;
 }
```

---

You can use [`setId()`](http://gwt-ext.com/docs/2.0.4/com/gwtext/client/widgets/grid/ColumnConfig.html#setId(java.lang.String)) method in `ColumnConfig`:

> Assigning id to ColumnConfig results in the column dom element having that ID. This is useful to apply custom css to the entire column.

If `id` = `note` then css rule should be:

```
.x-grid3-col-note {
      overflow: auto; white-space: normal !important;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you again Adam!  Your first suggestion worked.  The second one didn't, unless I did it wrong.  I'll add my attempt at that in the post.